# Two way binding is not working with angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have the html code like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<tr data-ng-repeat="element in awesomeThings">
      <div ng-if="$even">
          <td ng-click="getServiceDetails(element)">
              <a href="#">
                  {{element['serviceDetail']['name']}}
              </a>
          </td>
      </div>
  </tr>

  //after some html 
  <span >{{publicName}}</span>
</div>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('dcWithAngularApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$http,test) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = {"serviceDetail":{"name":"batman"}}

    $scope.getServiceDetails = function(serviceDetails)
    {
        console.log('Called')
        $scope.publicName = serviceDetails.name
    }
  });
```

After clicking on the `td` tag, the `span` text are not changing! Even though me changing the `publicName` in the current scope!

Where I'm making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `name` property in your `$scope.awesomeThings` `array`.

Here I added some animals for you.

```
angular.module('dcWithAngularApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$http,test) {

    $scope.awesomeThings = [
        { name: "Dog" },
        { name: "Cat" }
    ];

    $scope.getServiceDetails = function(serviceDetails)
    {
        console.log('Called')
        $scope.publicName = serviceDetails.name
    }
});
```

Edit:

I put together a *JSFiddle* that solves your edit.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7191/

Comment: nope `awesomeThings` is loaded with json after the rest calls.

Comment: Put in the value of `awesomeThings` after you populate it, in your question

Answer (score 0):

$scope.awesomeThings is an array of string so element does not have a 'name' property.

You also have a missing ; after your console.log which may be stopping the code from running.

It may help you to log what the object is.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<tr data-ng-repeat="element in awesomeThings">
      <div ng-if="$even">
          <td ng-click="getServiceDetails(element)">
              <a href="#">
                  {{element.name}}
              </a>
          </td>
      </div>
  </tr>

  //after some html 
  <span >{{publicName}}</span>
</div>



angular.module('dcWithAngularApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$http,test) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = {"serviceDetail":{"name":"batman"}};

    $scope.getServiceDetails = function(serviceDetails)
    {
        console.log(serviceDetails);
        $scope.publicName = serviceDetails.name;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your main issue is this:

```
$scope.publicName = serviceDetails.name
```

It needs to be

```
$scope.publicName = serviceDetails;
```

$scope.awesomeThings is an array of strings, not objects.  You're ng-repeating through the string array and passing the string to your getServiceDetails method, so 'serviceDetails' is just a string.

As an unrelated warning, I see you're using tr inside a div.  The tr should be inside a table, thead, or tbody.

Comment: Same answer as mine but yours is more complete. I don't understand the downvote either Tom.